# How to prevent execution of useFetch in nuxt3 when body was changed

Tags: nuxt.js, hook, nuxtjs3

Scenario:

1. There is login page.
2. We want to send request to server ONLY when login button is pushed.
3. We do not want to send request when user changed input.

This is my code:

```
const body = ref<{ identifier: string, password: string }>({
  identifier: '',
  password: ''
});

const {data, execute, error, pending} = await useFetch(`${config.public.baseUrl}/api/auth/local`, {
  body,
  lazy: true,
  method: 'post',
  immediate: false,
  watch: [],
})

async function login() {
  console.log("login");
  await execute();
}
```

and template

```
    <form @submit.prevent="login">
      <label for="email">
        Email
        <input type="text" v-model="body.identifier">
      </label>
      <label for="password">
        Password
        <input type="password" v-model="body.password">
      </label>

      <button>Login</button>
    </form>
```

unfortunately even if I do not click button this form will send `post` request to `/api/auth/local` every time when user type letter in this form.

This behavior is described in documentation:

https://nuxt.com/docs/api/composables/use-fetch

> All fetch options can be given a computed or ref value. These will be watched and new requests made automatically with any new values if they are updated.

**I need to override this feature.**

Change of

```
v-model
```

to

```
v-model.lazy
```

helps a little bit, but I still can't control exact time when this request is send.

---

My current workaround

```
const body = ref<{ identifier: string, password: string }>({
  identifier: 'user@ok.com',
  password: ''
});

const loginBody = ref<{ identifier: string, password: string }>({
  identifier: '',
  password: ''
});

const {data, execute, error, pending} = await useFetch(`${config.public.baseUrl}/api/auth/local`, {
  body: loginBody,
  lazy: true,
  method: 'post',
  immediate: false,
  watch: [],
})

async function login() {
  console.log("login");
  loginBody.value = body.value;
  await execute();
}
```

is not enough good, because it sends actually 2 requests in the same time, but first is immediately cancelled.

Comment: you can create a function that returns the body. Whenever the button is clicked the function will get the latest body data and then return.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i achieved my goal writing function

```js
async function login() {
  if(JSON.stringify(loginBody.value) === JSON.stringify(body.value)) {
    await execute();
  } else {
    loginBody.value = body.value;
  }
}
```

Request is executed once always when `login` function is called. It body changed his value, then assign to `loginBody` triggers request. In other case we executing is manually by `execute`.

Little over-engineered but works.

Answer (score 7):

I meet the same situation. You could just unref the option value for useFetch() by using `{...loginbody}`.

```
const { data } = await useFetch('/login', { method: 'post', body: {...loginbody} })
```

Comment: I think this is a prettier and faster solution, and works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set in the options `watch: false`

See more [here](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/15741#issuecomment-1622652063)

Comment: This is the correct answer OR dont make `body` a `ref()` in the first place (probably it makes no sense to do it anyway)

Answer (score 0):

Your body is a `ref()` and therefor your `useFetch()` will watch it and execute again when it changes. You have two options:

1. Don't use `ref()` for your body. Does it really need to be a ref? Is it used in `<template>`? If you dont need a variable in your template, or if you use it in your template but it never changes then it does not need to be a `ref()`
2. In your `useFetch()` set `watch: false` so it will not execute when your body `ref()` changes